# Coverting Polymer 2 to Polymer 3: modulizer ran out of memory?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, polymer-modulizer

I'm trying to [convert a Polymer 2 project to Polymer 3 using ***polymer-modulizer***](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer) but I'm getting an error about running out of memory. What do I need to do to move forward?

I ran this command at the terminal:

```
modulizer me/my-repo --npm-version 6.2.0
```

And I got an error that included the following

> (average mu = 0.061, current mu = 0.024) allocation failure
>
> ...
>
> ... near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

[Here is the complete log and stack trace.](https://jpst.it/1jTQM)

Comment: Seeing the same issue. I'm on Windows. Node 10.5. All attempts have failed to increase --max-old-space-size as described here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer/issues/428

Comment: Same error, any solutions ?

Comment: any update on above matter?